# How to find the only UILabel in a view and hide it?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I am adding a UILabel as a subview to a UIView and sometime later I want to hide it. It is assigned to a variable but I don't think setting the variables property `Hidden` after it's been added to the view will work (well it doesn't seem to anyway).

Is there a way to loop through the subviews in a view and then find the one that has a specific tag or is of type UILabel that I could then remove?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[containerView viewWithTag:kMyLabelTag] setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: It took me a while to get it working, I was too doing something wrong in the way I was putting the label on, I think I was putting 2 labels over each other so your code did work but i didn't visually see it. Is all good now though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)'s subviews property. It will contain a reference to the UILabel.

Having said that, you are probably not handling the UILabel variable correctly, since what you've described you're doing should work.